# Show that a ring is a division ring if it satisfies following property

Tags: ring-theory

Show that ring $R$ is a division ring if for each $0  \neq a \in R$, there exists a unique element $x \in R$ such that $axa = a$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You have given a very terse statement of a problem you want help with, but such brevity leaves Readers guessing where exactly help is needed.  Definitions are always a good starting point, and here the title (but not the body of the Question) mentions *division ring*.  Please edit the body of the Question to give a full statement of the problem to be solved, and include what context you can to help Readers respond at the level most useful to you.

Comment: You definitely need to absorb hardmath's advice about our community above in general, but in this case you also need another piece of advice: search for your question before asking. You are at least the fifth person to ask this exact question, and a search as simple as "division ring unique" revealed them.