# If R is a ring with unity , suppose $x \neq 0\in R, \exists $a unique $y \in R$ such that xyx = x, then show that xy = yx = 1

Tags: ring-theory

Not able to get any clue. can you tell me how to do this:

If $R$ is a ring with unity , suppose $x \neq 0\in R, \exists $a unique $y \in R$ such that $xyx = x$, then show that $xy = yx = 1$

Comment: are you stuck with existence or uniqueness? Can you do later steps if you assume the ones before?

Comment: Congratulations! You have earned a Xerox badge (create a duplicate of a question that already has four duplicates). You will get 5 copies of it in snail-mail.  All joking aside, please, *please* search for your question before you ask it.

Comment: Ugh... one of the duplicates was [yours, even](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2347990/29335). Why on earth would you re-post your question after having been pointed to the previous duplicates with solutions already? big -1. Your xerox badge is revoked, also.

Comment: ha ha ha ... i have not seen this. After posting, i have realised it a dup :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly remark that $L_x(a)=xa$ is injective. Suppose $xa=0$. This implies $x(y+a)x=xyx=xax=xyx=x$. Since $y$ is unique, $y+a=y$ and $a=0$.

$xyx=x$ impies $x(yx-1)=0$ implies $yx=1$ since $L_x$ is injective.

For the other equality, show $R_x(a)=ax$ is injective... mutatis mutandis.

Answer (score 1):

About injectivity of $L_x$, since $xa=0$ then $xax = 0 = x0x$ and so $a=0$ because of uniqueness.

Comment: Doh...The property that $y$ is the unique element such that $x=xyx$ apparently does not permit this deduction that "$xax=x0x \implies a=0$. We don't have any idea if either of these are equal to $x$... Regards

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right!